# can seem to submit form in codeigniter and go to next view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

below is my 'mainview.php'  view. from here iam attempting to submit and just open the next view which is called 'carerview.php'.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>login" method="post">                    
    <div class="input-prepend">
         <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
          <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="your@email.com"></br></br>

          <div class="input-prepend">
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
              <input type="password" id="" name="" placeholder="Password"></br></br>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>Sign in</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Iam  trying to submit this is giving me issues.The Index page loads which contains the above view. but when i submit . i get requested URL not found on this server
. then if i use the full url  action="application/controllers/user/login" i get a forbidden, dont have permission to access it.

my method in my controller class is just to load the next view on submit so i dont think there is an issue there . below is the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

            if(!$this->isLoggedIn())
            {
            $this->load->view('mainview');
            }
            else
            {
            //do something
            }

    }


    public function login()
    {
    $this->load->view('carerview');

    }



    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
    return false;
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What does your base_url() print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you didn't remove `index.php` from your URL and didn't set anything to `base_url` in configuration,try this

```
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/login

localhost/your_app_folder/index.php/controller/action
```

Comment: i set localhost/testapp to base_url in my config file

Comment: Vipin -full marks go to you. yes i didnt remove index.php via .htaccess. i guess this is something i should do really. that wat taking me far too much time.

Comment: I was just wondering is it a good idea to get rid of the index.php part of the url?

Comment: without index.php , URL looks better, I think

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is `base_url()`, which means is the application index route.

Try using `form_open()` (in the form_helper), which takes care of building the correct url:

```
<?php echo form_open('user/login');?>

  ... your form here

<?php echo form_close();?>   // since I didn't see a close form tag in your form
```

Be careful of any routes that might intercept the request.

Alternatively, you could use `site_url()`:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('user/login');?>">
```

Comment: the second solution resulted in this error "The requested URL /testapp/user/login was not found on this server." do i need to place the full url in there?

Comment: also in the first solution you gave do the php tags just replace the form tags?

Comment: again, if i use the full url iget a "forbidden message".

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess rules, or removed 'index.php' from the $config file? And yes, the `form_open()` / `form_close()` write the appropriate `<form>` tags for you

Comment: when i use the first method i get this error " Call to undefined function form_open() in C:\wamp\www\testapp\application\views\mainview.php on line 27"

Comment: It's in the form_helper (as I wrote), be sure you've loaded it `$this->load->helper('form')`. Refer to the manual for all the basics

Comment: any chance you could give a brief explanation of this, i read about it in the manaul and didnt understand it at all.

Comment: still doesnt seem to work even with the $this->load->helper('form') command. i get the error "The requested URL /testapp/user/login was not found on this server."  so i dont know where iam going wrong. do i need to have a .htaccess file?